How do I display Azure Deployment Center log history in Grafana
We have a set of Grafana dashboards which are connected to our Azure system and we have some useful data showing on these dashboards.
However there is 1 selection of data that is eluding me at present, this is Deployment Center logs. In Azure these are visible thus:


So my question is how do I display this on a Grafana dashboard, any ideas please?
Thanks in advance for any help on this.

There is a REST Api to access the logs
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/deployments?api-version=2023-12-01

See the docs.
Then, use the Infinity data source plugin for Grafana to visualize the data. There is a tutorial on how to do this based on the azure management api, which is the one you need.
